# How strong are the DLC commanders compared to vanilla commanders?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

Company of Heroes 2 came out today and introduced multiple so called "Commanders" as day zero DLC. So I am curious how strong they are compared to the commanders from the vanilla content. Can this game considered to be pay to win or is it neglectable?

Comment: Just a comment, but i am very annoyed that i paid 60$ and they want to charge me extra for commanders.  I highly doubt the DLC commanders are any stronger than the regular ones but I refuse to pay to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally pay to win, the new commanders offer things like

Vet3 tiger ace - for free, no matter what your resources.
Assault Grens who basically win any engagement in the first 5-10 mins.
Soviet industry - that lets you spam armour like crazy.

The simple fact that they are not part of the full priced game makes is what makes them pay to win strategies - even if you have the full priced game you can't play with them or even look at the details about them in the game.

I like the analogy of a game of chess.

Imagine White has paid to access to certain openings that are not available to Black. On top of the massive strategic advantage that offers, White can also place new pieces on the board that move in unique ways - moves which black may not know about.

It is the epitome of pay to win.